Roslyn analyzer for checking syntax of SQL literals in VS2022?
I have many commits described as some variation of "fixed error in SQL statement". Too many dumb mistakes like modifying a WHERE clause and leaving an extra AND keyword in it, things like that.
Is there a Roslyn analyzer that validates T-SQL syntax in string literals? Not looking for validation against the actual database, just clearing up syntax warnings would probably help us avoid some problems.
If not, does anybody have some good solutions for this? Not interested in switching to EF or recommendations like that, but for projects using micro ORM tools like Dapper that make use of SQL literals in code, if there are solutions to validate syntax at compile time or in unit testing, I'd be interested in hearing them.
These aren't database projects in Visual Studio, but like web or API projects where SQL statements are strings.

"T-SQL syntax in string literals"? Are you looking for something that will check the syntax of either (1) SQL fragments in string literals that are used to construct complete SQL statements, or (2) string literals containing fixed complete SQL statements (presumably invoked with parameters)? For #1, I doubt that such a tool exists, due to the complexity in making a tool that can predict what the final SQL will look like. #2 might be possible, but I am not an expert and am aware of such a tool. The answer might just be coding discipline - finding a way to test the SQL before committing.

Number 2, complete SQL statements. It seems like it would be doable, particularly if there were some type of attribute to indicate which constants or variables would contain the statements worth validating.
Was thinking that maybe short of Roslyn, a pattern for unit testing this stuff might exist by mocking db connection and running regex against the SQL statement that’s submitted to make sure it conforms to valid TSQL syntax. That’s more complex than I want to write myself, but thinking maybe someone’s been down this path before.

If you could generate the final SQL statement, then could you just use PARSEONLY? That might get you some of the way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-parseonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

@TN prepare to be amazed, then!

I consider myself Amazed.

Yes! Dapper.Advisor / Dapper.AOT already include a full T-SQL analyzer (that uses Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom internally), which automatically detects both Dapper usage and use of CommandText on SqlCommand - and has both general T-SQL checking and additional usage guidance. If you want something more bespoke, the code is on GitHub.
Example validator that shows a simple detected failure scenario here (although now I notice that the constructor usage isn't being validated - I've logged that to be fixed)

Is that System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand, or Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand (or both)? :)

@RichardDeeming for assuming TSQL? either; if you only have DbCommand etc, then the tooling also allows the syntax to be specified in code via attributes at any level(method, class, module, etc), or project properties / analyzer config: https://aot.dapperlib.dev/sqlsyntax

@RichardDeeming I found the definition set: https://github.com/DapperLib/DapperAOT/blob/0b5f6d7827d74632c1b239d6ceb9f9f4ea24e8d5/src/Dapper.AOT.Analyzers/Internal/Inspection.cs#L1456-L1468

This is amazing, Marc! Wow, that flew under my radar. I added Dapper.Advisor to my project, modified a string to add in an error to an existing SQL statement, compiled, and it caught it! Fantastic! It's also telling me I have all sorts of other problems in life like an overdependence on the asterisk symbol, but here I am chuckling like Butthead this morning nonstop. Thank you!! So excited about this!

@user71030 just remember you don't have to follow my biased preferences; if you like *: disable the rule and use it!
